# Perl, concatenation of 0s

Tags: perl, hash

I have the following code:

```
foreach $string (@strings) {
    if ($hash{$string}) {
        $letter = $hash{$string};
        $text .= $letter;
    }
}
```

where `$letter` is one character or one number (for example: a, e, o, 2, 5...). It creates a fine text, but I have problems with appending the number 0.

If `$letter = 0` it is not concatenated, giving for example `28` instead of `2008`. However, if `$letter` at that moment is `1` or `aaaa`, it gives `2118` or `2aaaaaaaa8`.

I was thinking that it might be something related to 0 and FALSE in Perl... might be?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You test to see if the entry exists using `if ($hash{$string})` but that also checks that the value is true. Use `if (defined $hash{$string})` instead.

Answer (score 3):

A value of `0` is defined but false. Check definedness rather than truth:

```
if (defined $hash{$string}) {
```

or using the [defined-or](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) operator:

```
$text .= $hash{$string} // '';
```

Answer (score 3):

`I was thinking that it might be something related to 0 and FALSE in Perl... might be?`

Yes, that is the issue.
The correct way to check whether a hash key is defined as follows

```
foreach $string (@strings) 
{
    if (defined $hash{$string}) # Check if key is defined
    {
        $letter = $hash{$string};
        $text .= $letter; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: So when key corresponds to value 0... it is defined or undefined? I can't understand the process...

Comment: So is `$hash{$string} ='';`